# MYSQL ERROR 2049 (HY000): Connection using old (pre-4.1.1) authentication protocol ref used (client option 'secure_auth' enabled)

Tags: mysql, authentication

when I tried to restore all database dump which is in 5.0 version to 5.6 version, it got restored and after that when I tried to reconnect, am getting the following error

`ERROR 2049 (HY000): Connection using old (pre-4.1.1) authentication protocol ref used (client option 'secure_auth' enabled)`..

I have tried adding the following lines in My.ini and restarted the service,but the issue persist till.

```
skip-grant-tables
```

The following link says its a bug in MYSQL.

https://github.com/santisaez/powerstack/blob/master/packages/mysql/mysql-powerstack-secure_auth.patch

Do anyone have any fixes for this solution?

Comment: As this is mostly related to DB administration you should probably ask this on http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use this workaround for MySQLWorkBench 6.0 at the Manage Server Connections Dialog Box:

Add useLegacyAuth=1 in the Advanced options box in the connection settings dialog.

Comment: I am trying to connect through mysql query browser. Where I should set this?

Comment: You should set it in the "Others" field of the "Advanced" tab of the connection properties. See the screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/Gxn07No.png

Comment: @LachlanArthur thanks for the screen shot, I did not have enough reputation to upload one.

Comment: Now there's a option for this in the "advanced" tab. It's called "Disabled secure_auth"

Comment: Worked like a charm ;D

Answer (score 13):

On the command line, use something like the following, if you have no choice...

```
mysql -uTheUseerNAme -pThePassword DbName -h HostName --skip-secure-auth
```

Hope this helps someone, as this was my problem connecting from a Linux box

Comment: Worked for me with `mysqldump` with MySQL Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.17, for Win32 (x86).

Answer (score 3):

Best thing to do is to reset your user password to the new hashing algorithm

With workbench: http://blogs.technicise.com/change-root-password-in-mysql-workbench/

Command line: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mysql-change-root-password/

Answer (score 2):

Fixed as of MySQL Workbench 6.0.7, and here's the changelog entry:

A new option was added in the connection settings "Advanced" tab for
disabling the secure_auth (useLegacyAuth) option, to optionally connect to
legacy systems.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For MySQL Workbench 6.08 in the Manage Server Connections, Connection tab, Advanced sub-tab you must check the box 'Use the old authentication protocol.'

Answer (score 1):

I've got same problem in Centos 7 with MySQL. If i try to connect by mysql client:

ERROR 2049 (HY000): Connection using old (pre-4.1.1) authentication protocol refused (client option 'secure_auth' enabled)

Bu in my case if I specify:

--skip-secure-auth

it cause error message:

ERROR 1275 (HY000): Server is running in --secure-auth mode, but 'root'@'localhost' has a password in the old format; please change the password to the new format

It work only when i specify:

in /etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
...
secure_auth=false
```

and then restart mysqld

Comment: With MySQL 5.6.17 included in WAMP 2.5, i have configure to use both `--skip-secure-auth` and `secure_auth=false` to work. Thanks btw.

Answer (score 0):

Using the way like rayVenues but you should change your password connection, it will work fine :)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, but using MAC Terminal connecting remote MySQL db.

Solution: I create a new user with less special characters, that problem disappeared.