# Error on MySQL Data Import

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to import to a schema in MySQL workbench but get the following error:

**ERROR 2049 (HY000): Connection using old (pre-4.1.1) authentication protocol refused (client option 'secure_auth' enabled)**

I had a similar problem trying to connect originally to the schema and solved it by following the fixes in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18126513/mysql-error-2049-hy000-connection-using-old-pre-4-1-1-authentication-protoc)  but I can't do this import still.  I can now access the schema fine, but when I try to do the import it fails with this same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not a bug, if you use your user account password with old hashing algorithm. you can try with new account with new algorithm password by following step -

1. set session old_passwords = 'OFF';
2. create user 'test' IDENTIFIED BY 'TESTPASS';

Now you can connect with this account and try to import. I hope it will help to you.

Comment: Thanks Tanim.  I changed the password and it didn't help.  I worked round it with phpMyAdmin in the end as I couldn't get it to work.